# FAT32 Structure

Tags: filesystems, fat32, embedded

Is there any tool available which can provide some form of dump of the physical locations of files on a FAT32 filesystem ?

I am investigating a corruption issue with an embedded system and a critical file seems to have been corrupted by something writing a 32-bit counter over some of the file data.

I would like to find out where this data is in order to track down how this happened.

Comment: You do understand that basically every operating with FAT32 filesystem other than Windows is basically unofficial. Microsoft has only licensed FAT32 to a very small subset of companies Apple is one of those companies. You don't indicate what operating system this tool needs to run on.  Without that information we cannot help, even though, this is very close to a product recomendation question.

Comment: Runtime's DiskExplorer Fat Version (http://www.runtime.org/diskexplorer.htm) and Raise Data Recovery (http://www.ufsexplorer.com/rdr_fat.php) are two such tools if you can mount the file system on a Windows machine.